# Long running report causes network timeout. How to throw exception?

Tags: java, servlets, jsf-2, richfaces, websphere

I am calling a 3rd party report api to run reports.  The api accepts a HttpRequest and Repsonse and writes the report to the response.  There are cases where these reports take a long time to run( and a network timeout(5 minutes) occurs causing the browser popup window to stay blank.  No "page not found error" or any other type of error is ever displayed.

The client has a requirement to detect the network timeout has occured and show an error page in the window.  Ive searched through the forum and i see a lot about session timeout.  This is not a session timeout.  Any ideas how to force my own timeout and redirect to an error page after a time of my choosing?

Im using JSF 2/Richfaces 4.0/Webshpere 7

One quick note.  I cannot change the requirements.  I must call this api and i must display an error.  I cannot switch to a solution to keep the connection alive or use any type of push

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to handle connection timeout by your client code. you can do the API call via ajax and config an acceptable timeout value to meet the requirement.
here is a reference I searched from google, maybe it will be helpful.[Handling timeouts gracefully in AJAX using client-side code](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/03/07/71625.aspx)

Added note: you can simply use setTimeout(handler,300000)  and check api return value in the handler, if still not returned, call window.location.href='your redireced url'.